# Can you execute a create table from Datastax driver with session.execute?

Tags: java, cassandra, prepared-statement, datastax, cql

com.datastax.driver.core.Session

for example:

```
//This works
session.execute ("select * from table");
//This returns a nullpointer
session.execute ("create table testtable ( number int, string varchar)");
```

Do I have to use some sort of schema builder?
NOTE: im connected to the cassandra instance and can query it no problem. I just want to be able to create tables from the datastax driver

Answer (score 3):

What error do you get when trying to `CREATE` a table?

As for some quick things to try, it's possible that your user might be missing the `CREATE` permission.

```
session.execute ("create table testtable ( number int, string varchar)");
```

Another thing I noticed about this statement, was that you don't seem to be specifying a `PRIMARY KEY`.  All tables in Cassandra *must* have a primary key.

Try altering your CQL to this, and see if it helps:

```
create table testtable ( number int, string varchar, PRIMARY KEY (number))
```